# Dereference variable inside list

Tags: scheme

Is it possible to dereference a variable contained inside a list, to obtain its value? For example:

```
(define one 1)
(define two 2)

(define list '(one two))

(display (list-ref list 0))
```

Here `list-ref` references to `one`, and `display` shows `one` in letters. Could instead `one` dereference to the value contained by the homonym variable?

Comment: Note that if you don't actually want/need a list of symbols, you can just do `(define my-list (list one two))  (display list-ref my-list 0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eval can definitely solve this problem... but like most situations where eval is applicable, it's a large and dangerous hammer.

Matthew Flatt's blog post on this topic has become the go-to explanation:

http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html

Here's how you might do it without eval in Racket. Stripping away the cruft, "dict-ref" can find a named
element (or elements) in an "association list".

```
#lang racket

(define data
  '((one 1)
    (two 2)))


(define wanted-list '(two one))

;; evaluates to '((2) (1)):
(for/list ([wanted wanted-list])
  (dict-ref data wanted))
```

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because the quoted list contains two symbols, `one` and `two`. Try the following:

`(display (eval (list-ref list 0)))`

To resolve that symbol.

Comment: In general, you should avoid `eval` in simple situations like this, for the reasons described in the blog post John links to below.